# HP UFT .Net Extensibility overrides existing support of control

Tags: .net, qtp, hp-uft

I want to add some methods for object that is already supported by UFT.
I've created .Net DLL and added configuration to SwfConfig.xml. Now UFT can replay only my methods for this object.

Is it possible to have both UFT out-of-box methods and custom extensibility methods?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.  When creating extensibility in VS, you can select the object that your custom control will be MappedTo under the XML Configuration settings.

Comment: Thank you for reply!
The problem is that I'm using .Net Extensibility and there is no such functionality there. You can set Class Type for you extensibility in SwfConfig.xml. That is what I did. But it does not work.

Comment: I have revised my answer for .NET,  mistakenly replied for Web.  What you're trying to do is possible, you can see here:  http://technodivine.com/downloads/Help-and-Guides/02-QTP/01-QTP-Documentation-9.5/08-QTP-9.5-NETExtDevGuide.pdf on page 35.

Comment: I map to SwfTable in SwfConfig.xml but it does not fix problem. I'm customizing Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.